# Variables in IntelliJ's Run/Debug Configurations

Tags: java, configuration, junit, intellij-idea

I am wanting to set up a Run/Debug Configuration in IntelliJ for JUnit. I know how to set it up to run a specific `package`, a specific `class`, or a specific `method`. I was wondering if there was a way to set up the configurations so it will run the currently opened `Class` file or the currently selected test `method`. I would imagine I would put something like this in the `Class` field of the `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog box:

```
my.package.tests.${currentTest}
```

or something like that. Is there a way to accomplish this so I don't have to make a Run/Debug Configuration for each test class I want to run?

Comment: if you right click on test method there is an option to run only that method.

Comment: @Joel : please change your question title, since answer you accepted wasn't about "Variables in IntelliJ's Run/Debug Configurations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the right-click > "run testYourtest()" or the shortcut define in the keymap as "Run context configuration".

Usually it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: so I don't have to add a new configuration in the Run/Debug Configuration?

Answer (score 2):

If you need specific settings for all you tests you can change the defaults e.g. add -ea.  This way you don't need a configuration for each test.

BTW: YoU can run all the tests in a package, by selecting the package first.  Sometimes it is better to run a group of tests to check you haven't changed something unintended.